# Unable to change facebook app to live mode from development mode

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the facebook login in my app. When I configured the fb app using their doc and I try to change the app to live mode, I couldn't. It shows "store id not found in public markets - Your app must be available in every public store in order take your app Live. Make sure the ID (package name) is valid or remove the platform until the app is available."

I think they may changed the restriction recently. Don't know.
Can anyone help me to get this working?

Comment: 1 : Copy your Android app details in Notepad and remove your Android App from facebook developer console.     2: Now make app live 3: now add your Android app back to console

Comment: Thanks bro. Its working

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks @RutvikBhatt I think you should consider making this an answer instead.

Comment: @JohnDavid already Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908127/6454463)

Comment: Check this answer too :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50961697/3974530