# Your app must be available in every public store in order take your app Live. Facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating Facebook login in my android app. So in order to get the user basic information I have to make my app live from Facebook developer console.

My problem is it doesn't let me do so. It gives me the following error

`Your app must be available in every public store in order to take your app Live.`

I have also added privacy policy URL and
Contact Email suggested in  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35191508)  answer and tried to make public but every time it gives me same error.

I have done Facebook integration before and there was no problem making app live.
I have also added test users but they never get any request either on mail or on Facebook.

In my app, I am successfully able to log in but after login it says 
`App not setup`.

My app is not available at play store right now. So can we not use Facebook integration before making app live in play store. or am I missing something?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1 > Open your facebook developers dashboard.

2 > find the Android app.

3 > copy the details in the notepad.

4 > Remove Android app from Dashboard.

5 > Now make your app public(Live).

6 > re-enter your Android app data into Dashboard.

Thats it. :)

Comment: your answer is really helpful :)

Comment: @Rutvik Bhatt, how can I get back the app if I remove it?

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty Add the data that you copied (as per step 3) in the notepad back to the console

Comment: @RutvikBhatt, please guide me as I am not understanding how can you copy an app in notepad.

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty Copy the data from the Facebook console like KeyHashes, package name and class name so you don' t need to regenerate that data.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt, but once the app is deleted, under what ID shall I put the KeyHashes, package name and the other stuff?

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty You don't need to delete the whole app you just need to remove your android app(platform) details.

Comment: Sorry @RutvikBhatt! I tried but am the app isn't changing to Live mode. It's showing the error message.

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty Contact me on LinkedIn or Twitter. I'll take a remote or give verbal instructions to you  to solve the issue