# Store ID not found in public markets android facebook error

Tags: android, facebook

I am getting this error. Please help me to solve this.

**Store ID not found in public markets**

> Your app must be available in every public store in order take your
>   app Live. Make sure the ID com.test.app is valid or remove the
>   platform until the app is available.

Comment: refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908127/6454463)

Comment: Did you published your app? Or it is in progress?

Comment: no it is not published just i start the work on it

Answer (score 1):

As per you comment, your application is in progress. So till the time (until you publish it) you can not mark your application live.

So Facebook gives a way to use facebook API including login before publishing app using test or dev users. You need to add set of user with defined role as test or dev. For those users you can use login api or other facebook api.

Read more at [How to create Test Users for Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/)

---

Or you can add some facebook users in role section available like below

[image]

Here you need to add id. For example if user's profile url is `https://www.facebook.com/userAtFacebook`, id which you will add is `userAtFacebook`. After adding that user `userAtFacebook` will get notification to accept invite. That user needs to accept that. And that's it.

Comment: yeah that's true. thank u